# Analogy between `F[_ <: A] <: B` at type-level and `f: A => B` at value-level

Tags: scala, scala-3, type-constructor

Assuming `F[_ <: A] <: B` as type-level analog of `f: A => B`, let `[F[_ <: Int] <: List[Int], A <: Int]`, then should't type application `F[A]` yield `List[Int]` when `A = Int`, so `f(List(42))` should compile in the following case

```
$ scala3-repl
scala> def f[F[_ <: Int] <: List[Int], A <: Int](as: F[A]) = as
def f[F[_$1] <: List[Int], A <: Int](as: F[A]): F[A]

scala> f(List(42))
1 |f(List(42))
  |  ^^^^^^^^
  |Found:    List[Int]
  |Required: F[A]
  |
  |where:    A is a type variable with constraint <: Int
  |          F is a type variable with constraint <: [_$1 <: Int] =>> List[Int]
```

Applying the error message by explicitly providing type parameters makes it work

```
scala> f[[_ <: Int] =>> List[Int], Int](List(42))
val res0: List[Int] = List(42)
```

Where does the analogy break? Where is my mental model of considering `F[_ <: Int] <: List[Int]` as a type-level function from `Int` to `List[Int]` wrong?

Comment: [Consider these variations](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/R4DtgU5zShmjQjZwkvWWWQ). Scala is not smart enough to deduce bounds on F[_] from bounds on its arguments, which is unfortunate (and might even be a bug).

Comment: @MarioGalic @HTNW Not true `type N[X <: 42] = List[Int]; f[N, Int](List(42))` would fail but `type N[X <: AnyVal] = List[Int]; f[N, Int](List(42))` compiles. `X` is in a contravariant position it can only be wider than `Int` and not narrower. There's still an implication on the type bound of `X`.

Comment: And `type N[X <: String] = List[Int]; f[N, Int](List(42))` would fail as well because the bounds don't even overlap.

Comment: And on the covariant position you can narrow: `type N[X <: Int] = List[42]` but you can't widen: `type N[X <: Int] = List[AnyVal]`

Comment: @HTNW also in your last example
```
// in g, F[A] when A = Int does not have to be List[Int]
g[N, Int](Nil): List[Nothing]
```
but `List[Nothing]` is a `List[Int]` since `Nothing` is a subtype of all types and `List` is covariant.

Comment: `implicitly[List[Nothing] <:< List[Int]]` / `summon[List[Nothing] <:< List[Int]]` this is not a bug.

Comment: Just to note all my `f`s refers to @MarioGalic's `f` and all my `g`s refers to the one @HTNW examples, i,e. all my `f`s and `g`s are the same function.

Comment: @yangzai What is "not true"? Note that List[Nothing] *is not* List[Int]. *Each* List[Nothing] is a List[Int]. The types are different, so e.g. the "application F[A]" does *not* "yield List[Int]" as mistakenly put in the question (you misrepresent what I say when you use <:< instead of =:=). And the "bug" is that Scala does not think List is valid for F with bounds F[_ <: Int] <: List[Int], even though passing List a subtype of Int does produce a subtype of List[Int]. It might even be intentional, for some arcane reason. I don't know what your examples with other bounds are supposed to show.

Comment: @HTNW I see what you mean for the nothing case - the type param contradicts with the explicit return type. But for `F[_ <: Int] <: List[Int]`,  `type N[A] = List[Int]` is fine because `A` is allowed to be wider but not narrower. `List` is essentially `type N[A] = List[A]` and now `List[A]` is wider that `List[Int]` it is not allowed at that position.

Comment: `type N[A <: Int] = List[A]` would be fine but its not the same as `List`

Comment: for the nothing case you were using `type N[A] = List[Nothing]`  it doesn't depend on `A` so I don't see anything wrong with it but I assumed you brought it up in your examples because you have issues with it.

Comment: also in `type N[A] = List[Nothing]` `A` is wider that `A <: Int` and `List[Nothing]` is narrower than `List[Int]` so that is fine.

Comment: `type F[A] = B` is similar to  `A => B` -- A is in a contravariant position, B is in a covariant position.

Comment: @ HTNW The "not true" was particularly on @MarioGalic's comments that everything still compiles without the bound on `X`, ie the bound does nothing, but that has to depend on if the bound is wider or narrower. I don't think that comment is still there.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly regarding inferring type lambdas, I think that type inference would not go to the extent of coming up with type lambdas just to satisfy the constraints otherwise intuitively it would seem like everything would essentially be able typecheck with some convoluted type lambda and that would not be useful in picking up type errors.

As to why `f[List, Int](List(42))` fails to compile (and thus fails to get inferred) we would need to refer to the [Subtyping Rules](https://dotty.epfl.ch/docs/reference/new-types/type-lambdas-spec.html#subtyping-rules) of type lambdas:

> Assume two type lambdas
>
> ```scala
> type TL1  =  [X >: L1 <: U1] =>> R1
> type TL2  =  [X >: L2 <: U2] =>> R2
> ```
>
> Then `TL1 <: TL2`, if
>
> - the type interval `L2..U2` is contained in the type interval `L1..U1` (i.e. `L1 <: L2` and `U2 <: U1`),
> - `R1 <: R2`

Also note that:

> A partially applied type constructor such as `List` is assumed to be equivalent to its eta expansion. I.e, `List = [X] =>> List[X]`. This allows type constructors to be compared with type lambdas.

Which means all of these will compile:

```scala
f[[_ <: Int] =>> List[Int], Int](List(42)) //author's compiler example
f[[_] =>> List[Int], Int](List(42)) //input type bounds can be wider, output stays the same
f[[_] =>> List[42], Int](List(42)) //input wider, output narrower
f[[x <: Int] =>> List[x], Int](List(42))//input same, output narrower
```

And all of these will not:

```scala
f[[x] =>> List[x], Int](List(42)) //input type bounds can be wider but in this case it will also make the output wider
f[List, Int](List(42)) //equivalent to preceding case
f[[_ <: 42] =>> List[Int], Int](List(42)) //input type bounds cannot be narrower
```

In the case of:

```scala
def f[F[x] <: List[x], A <: Int](as: F[A]) = as
```

If you view it from the same type lambda perspective `f[[x] =>> List[x], Int](List(42))` should work, and thus `f[List, Int](List(42))` would also compile (and be inferred).

Comment: Scala 2 equivalence of `f[[_ <: Int] =>> List[Int], Int](List(42))` with `kind-projector`: ``f[λ[`* <: Int` => List[Int]], Int](List(42))``.


Without `kind-projector`: `f[({type λ[_ <: Int] = List[Int]})#λ, Int](List(42))` or `type L[_ <: Int] = List[Int]; f[L, Int](List(42)): List[Int]`.